# Coverting To Bytes In C

Tags: c

My teacher has developed a server that generates random characters and numbers. I need to create a program that takes what is generated and put it in standard input form and find the amount of bytes using the sizeof() operator. Also, if a random end of file occurs then it should generate a message and how many bytes have come through. I am a basic coder and need a little help with my program because I have no clue where to go from here to fix my mistake.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  int input;
  int sum;
  int size;

  do {
    size = sizeof(input);
    sum =+ size;
    input = 0;
  } while (scanf("%c", &input)!=EOF);

  if (EOF) {
    printf("Random End of File Has Occured.\n%d Bytes Have Been Received.", sum);
  }

  else {
    printf("End of Transmission Completed.\n%d Bytes Have Been Received.", sum);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of what I need it to look like:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Tia.png)

```
267.625293748653
5233.717459639272
29779
6489
3579.434430982391
28896
8834
3152.852412488174
25321
8320
28836
8875.864858351391
9539.445326098274
3859.598437452315
12345
195.324900951882
25139
22473
595.885992279732
2765.982421338542
6554.456891649837
5822.693258461257
9979.479628894926
193.095583971679
9349.095348739159
7462

Read 447 bytes from standard input
C:\Users\Brett\Downloads\hw2 (1)>
```

Comment: "here's my homework assignment, please fix my program without a description of the problem" is not a question.

Comment: _find the amount of bytes using the sizeof() operator_ ??? Count receive BYTE  instead of.

Comment: an example please text, not an image.

Comment: `sum =+ ...`  --> `sum += ...`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Note that `=+` is same as `+=` on _old_ compilers.  Perhaps K&R C.  Still likely a coding error on OP's part.

Comment: @chux  I bought a Japanese version in 1986, but such an operator does not exist. I guess you are thinking too much. The questioner looks younger.;-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Well even K&C edition 1 does not have `=+`, so it must have been another compiler in those _pre-standard_ C89 days.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you will need to fix.

1. You need to initialize `sum = 0;` before you start adding size to it `sum += size;`.  The way you have it now the `sum` variable has been initialized with garbage because it is on the stack.  Essentially, you are adding a known size to a garbage value.
2. Your code is not adding `size` to `sum`.  You need to change `sum =+ size;` to `sum += size;`

Hope this helps!